# ASP.NET Core 2.2 am getting an error on my OnModelCreating method after upgrading to Core 3.0

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am upgrading my .net core 2.2 project to release .net core 3.0 version.
While upgrading project, I have also updated the below packages.

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer with version 3.0.0
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools with version 3.0.0
3. Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL with version 3.0.0.

But i am getting below error

> Error CS1061  'IMutableEntityType' does not contain a definition for
>   'Relational' and no ccessible extension method 'Relational' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'IMutableEntityType' could be found are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please see the code and getting error on line number 2:

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
 .Select(e => e.Relational()).ToList()
 .ForEach(t => t.TableName = t.TableName.ToLower());
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a breaking change based on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#provider-specific-metadata-api-changes) and you should use `GetTableName` and `SetTableName` instead

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(e => e.SetTableName(e.GetTableName().ToLower()));
```